# Why haven't more of Bernard Werber's works been translated?

Tags: translation, publishing

[*Empire of the Ants*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_of_the_Ants_(novel)) is a translation of the first in a trilogy of books "*Les Fourmis*" by [Bernard Werber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Werber).

Quoting the Wikipedia article:

> Les Fourmis (English: The Ants) is a 1991 science fiction novel by French writer Bernard Werber. It was released in English as Empire of the Ants. The book sold more than two million copies and has been translated into more than 30 languages.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> It was also taken to video game format.

Given the relative [success](https://www.npr.org/2015/09/19/441459103/when-it-comes-to-book-sales-what-counts-as-success-might-surprise-you?t=1633306846730) of this I wonder why haven't more of his books and in particular the rest of the trilogy ever been translated into English?

Are there any statements about this by the publisher or the author?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to lit. It's an interesting question, but I worry the answers to this one can only be opinion-based, which is not a great match for a Q&A site. Any ideas on how to rewrite it as something which can get a definitive answer are welcome.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Your question currently has two close votes because it looks opinion based. It can be turned into a factual question by asking whether there any statements about this by the author or his publishers. That should solve the issue with the close votes. (Whether that question would be answerable is a different matter.)